# Get to print temperature only from one place in specific Puebla Mexico, with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to print with a .text(), the current temperature from Puebla Mexico only, and i have a function that works fine, but does not print the temperature of the location i want, someone knows what i am missing. I know that the ip api domain from Puebla Mexico is 201.165.55.2, but when i call for a Json object it grabs the temperature of another region, does someone knows why? here is the code.

var cTemp;

```
var outside = $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(data2){
    var api='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=19.051388888889&lon=-98.2177777777783&appid=cd380bb8125ea7190ceb6ca01bc0f681';

    $.getJSON(api, function(data){
        var kelvin = data.main.temp;
        cTemp = kelvin - 273;
        $(".pueblatemp").text(cTemp.toFixed(2) + " °C");
        $(".pueblatemp").prepend("Temperatura exterior: ");

        //Difference of temperature
        var a = Math.abs(cTemp);
        var b = Math.abs(x);

        var total = a + b;

        $('.difference').text(total.toFixed(2) + " °C");
        console.log(total);
        $(".difference").prepend("Diferencia: ");

    });
});
```

Also i am adding the result with another variable, but that adding is alright, i just want to get the temperature of Puebla in specific all the time.

Comment: In the returned json, I can see this: "name":"Puebla de Zaragoza". Isn't it the location you are looking for based on your "lat" and "lon"?

Comment: yes but when i search for the http://ip-api.com, it tells me it is from Leon, another city of Mexico. I think this is changing my result

Comment: This link http://ip-api.com/json returns a json data of the visitor ip address, So if you get the "lat" and "lon" from it and add them to your other ajax call `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=19.051388888889&lon=-98.2177777777783&appid=cd380bb8125ea7190ceb6ca01bc0f681`, Then it should provide weather info for that place. But I can not  see in your code, where you are extracting requested data from the `data2` json response...

Comment: o so i understand the  ip-api.com, its just for the request and it is not what is being printed, so the api im using is correct right? I think that the data2 is not being use, actually i changed to data and its working

Comment: I really do not know your logic and what you want to do and neither do not know the relation between these two APIs for you. I just noticed that you are sending ajax request to "ip-api.com/json" but never using the data getting from it. So what is the reason of sending this request in the first place? But now if you could sort it out, then it's fine anyway :)